# Zend Framework 2 Image Uploader Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, image-uploading

I am having a issue in uploading images from Zend Framework2 It worked fine for but now it give an issue saying "File was not found" when I print the Adapter and I need to have 2 file Uploaders in the same form

Here is my controller coding for file uploading

> ```
>             $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
>             $files = $adapter->getFileInfo();
>             $mediaFileHttpPostName = 'attr_image';
> ```

```
            $imageFile = $files[$mediaFileHttpPostName];



            $adapter->setDestination('./public/media');
            // $adapter->addValidator('Extension', false, array('jpge'), $mediaFileHttpPostName);

            $adapter->addFilter('Rename',
                array(
                    'target'=>  './public/media/'.$imageFile['name'],
                    'overwrite'=>true),
                $mediaFileHttpPostName);



            if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                $returnObject->errorMessage = $adapter->getMessages();
                $returnObject->result = 0;
            } else {
                try {
                    $adapter->receive($mediaFileHttpPostName);
                    $returnObject->result = 1;
                } catch (\Zend\Filter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                    $returnObject->errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                    $returnObject->result = 0;
                }
            }

            $resizeObj = new Imageresize('./public/media/'.$imageFile['name']);
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(400, 300, 'auto');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/uploads/attraction/main_image/'.$imageFile['name'], 100);

            $attra->setAttrImage($imageFile['name']);
```

Comment: try this:             $resizeObj = new Imageresize($imageFile['tmp_name']); basically the image still not saved.. so it should be on the temporary folder. var_dump($imageFile); to see what options you have